# AS3 Loading a Class using getDefinition()

Tags: actionscript-3, scripting, action

I have hit a road block on this and would highly appreciate if someone can help me on this, please. What I am trying to do is to use shared runtime library by loading a swf ('index.swf') which has numerous library objects which are named in sequence such as:

(orange1,orange2,orange3,orange4)
(red1,red2,red3,red4)

I am able to load the swf('index.swf') without any issues and even am able to load the right library asset, but I have to declare the full name as string such as getDefinition('orange1'). What I would like to do is to match first three letters of string and then run a for loop to load up all the classes that match the first three letters. I usually can do this by employing indexOf() method.

here is my code:

```
public function loadContent():void
{

ldr.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, progressHandler);
ldr.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onloadHandler);
ldr.load(req);

}

public function progressHandler(eProgress:ProgressEvent):void
{
var percent:Number = (eProgress.bytesLoaded / eProgress.bytesTotal);
trace(percent);
}

public function onloadHandler(e:Event):void
{
// THIS IS WHERE I AM TRYING TO MATCH THE STRING
var str:String = "red";
str = (str.indexOf(str));
var ref1:Class = e.currentTarget.applicationDomain.getDefinition(str) as Class
trace(ref1);

}
```

I would highly appreciate your help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your problem lies in the following lines of code:

```
str = (str.indexOf(str));
var ref1:Class = e.currentTarget.applicationDomain.getDefinition(str) as Class
```

indexOf() returns the index of the first occurrence of the specified substring or -1 if the substring doesn't exist. So , you are passing a string representation of some int (either -1 or 0, 1, 2, etc) to getDefinition()... which probably isn't returning a class reference.

Assuming you have some clips named red1, red2, red3, red4 I would do something like the following:

```
for (var i:int=0; i < 4; i++) {
     var classRef:Class = e.currentTarget.applicationDomain.getDefinition("red" + (i+1).toString()) as Class;
     trace(classRef);
}
```

Comment: Thank you heavilyinvolved. Appreciate your time and help.